# Where should exceptions been thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a class that looks the following way:

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    private string _question;

    public string Question {
        get { return _question;  }
        set { _question = value; }
    }

    public StackOverflowQuestion(string question) {
        _question = question;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return _question;
    }
}
```

Now, the value "question" isn't allowed to be null or empty and the user should be notified via a ArgumentNullException - but where should it been thrown? According to the 'fail-fast' principle -> Everywhere.

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    private string _question;

    public string Question {
        get { return _question;  }
        set { 
           if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                _question = value
            else throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
    }

    public StackOverflowQuestion(string question) {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(question))
            _question = question;
        else throw new ArgumentNullException("question");
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_question)) return _question;
        else throw new ArgumentNullException("_question");
    }
}
```

Now this is obviously ridiculous and extremely repetitive. But it seems right: If the value is set through .ctor, it fails directly after a short check. When its set through the property, it fails directly after a short check.. but who expects exceptions on a setter? And when I output the string, I expect a string, not an exception for something that should have happend long ago, but again: If it's wrong, it should fail ASAP, even if 'soon' is quite late.

So, where should the only exception handling been done? Am I asking for a 'best-practice', or is this a taste thing?

Comment: ToString should not throw exception

Comment: Can you elaborate why not?

Comment: @Atrotygma: Because it can never get into that state...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since _question is private, there's no need to check whether it is null in ToString() (unless you're just sanity checking your own code).

You can avoid the check in the constructor by having the constructor use the property setter. Thus, I'd recommend:

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    private string _question;

    public string Question {
        get { return _question;  }
        set { 
           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                // to make this more transparent when thrown through the constructor, it might
                // be preferable to throw a real error message like "Question: cannot be null or empty"
                throw new ArgumentException("value");
           this._question = value;
        }
    }

    public StackOverflowQuestion(string question) {
        this.Question = question;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Question;
    }
}
```

A few things to note:
1. You should throw `ArgumentException` rather than `ArgumentNullException` for empty strings (if you want you can do 2 checks and still throw `ArgumentNullException` for nulls).
2. While the approach uses less code, the one disadvantage is that the error message users get is slightly worse than when they pass null to the constructor, since the failure happens 2 levels deep instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to test it *once* - in the single place where you set the variable, having changed the constructor to use the property:

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion
{
    private string _question;

    public string Question
    {
        get { return _question; }
        set
        { 
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
           {
               throw new ArgumentException("Question cannot be null or empty",
                                           "value");
           }
           _question = value;
        }
    }

    public StackOverflowQuestion(string question)
    {
        Question = question;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Question;
    }
}
```

The one downside here is that the "bad parameter" name will be `value` rather than `question` when it's null in the constructor, but I think that's a price worth paying. An alternative is *just* to use the message, and not specify the parameter name.

You *may* want to separate out `null` from `empty`, so that you can throw an `ArgumentNullException` when it's null - but you shouldn't be throwing `ArgumentNullException` when it's just empty.

You don't need to perform any checks when *fetching* the value, as you know it will never be null or empty, because you're preventing it from ever being set that way.

You should also consider whether you could make the class immutable, at which point you'd only need to test in the constructor as there wouldn't be a setter...

Comment: This is what I thought too first, but in that case the exceptions gets thrown on the property - this gives a stack trace that I'm not expecting because I gave the variable to the ctor, not to the property. Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: I think the .NET framework convention is to use the property name rather than "value". It certainly conveys a little more information.

Comment: @Atrotygma: The stack trace still includes the call that you *did* make - I don't think you should expect the stack trace to always be *directly* at the point you called.

Comment: @Tragedian: Why? The property name is in the stack trace, surely. (`Question_set()` or whatever.)

Comment: You'd have to ask the BCL team why they do it. From my observation, it means the exception message (which is always emphasised over the stack trace) contains enough information to know what the nature of the problem is without requiring a look at the stack trace. It also works well with the standard message structure they follow: "Value cannot be null. ParamName: Question"

Comment: @Tragedian: Hmm... I really haven't seen that before. I wonder how pervasive it is. I'm not terribly bothered either way, to be honest. Do you know if it's documented anywhere? (I can't see it in the normal Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers.)

Comment: @JonSkeet But I do. I expect the program to fail ASAP, so when I take a look under the hood and see that the stack trace contains events that happened later, it's against the idea of failing immediately. What if you use the IErrorHandler interface in a web service? A normal stack trace would go .ctor -> Exception -> fail, but now you have .ctor -> property_set -> Exception -> IErrorHandler -> various other stuff -> maybe sometime...

Comment: @Atrotygma: It still fails immediately - it's not like it returns and fails later. Nor does it in any way make it unclear what the problem is. Anyway, you can decide for yourself: do you want code duplication, or shorter stack traces? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, then it seems to be a taste thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather make it immutable:

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion
    {
        public string Question
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public StackOverflowQuestion(string question)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(question))                
              throw new ArgumentNullException("question");

            Question = question;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Question;
        }
    }
```